# How to get email id from facebook using Grails social plugin

Tags: grails, oauth, facebook-oauth

I am using **spring-security-oauth-facebook:0.1** grails plugin in my application.Now i want to access person's email id but i am not able each time facebook server respond **1829812989120** for socialId ,Username, profileId and there is no option of email in returning Map object.Why it is happening.

```
     oauth {
        debug = true
           providers {
    facebook {
        api = org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
        key = 'my-app-key'
        secret = 'secret-key'
        successUri = '/oauth/facebook/success'
        failureUri = '/oauth/facebook/failure'
        callback = "${baseURL}/oauth/facebook/callback"
        scopes = "['public_profile','email','name','user']"

      } 

    def sessionKey = oauthService.findSessionKeyForAccessToken(provider)

    if (!session[sessionKey]) {
        log.warn "No OAuth token in the session for provider '${provider}'"
        throw new OAuthLoginException("Authentication error for provider '${provider}'")
    }
    // Create the relevant authentication token and attempt to log in.

    OAuthToken oAuthToken = springSecurityOAuthService.createAuthToken(provider, 
                                                                            session[sessionKey])
    println "oAuthToken.principal = "+oAuthToken.principal.toString();
    println "oAuthToken.socialId  = "+oAuthToken.socialId;
    println "oAuthToken.properties= "+oAuthToken.properties
    println "oAuthToken.properties= "+oAuthToken.name
    println "oAuthToken.properties= "+oAuthToken.toString();
```

1)I ckecked all println value email is not there. 
please help me how to get email address of logged in user.

Comment: Take a look on https://github.com/manishkbharti/FacebookOauth

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i checked all values everywhere i am getting only digit.

Comment: Are u there abdullah

Answer (score 11):

Use this code after session created

```
OAuthToken oAuthToken = springSecurityOAuthService.createAuthToken(provider, 
                                                                        session[sessionKey])
Token facebookAccessToken = (Token) session[oauthService.findSessionKeyForAccessToken('facebook')]

println "Facebook token :"+facebookAccessToken

def facebookResource = oauthService.getFacebookResource(facebookAccessToken ,    "https://graph.facebook.com/me")

def facebookResponse = JSON.parse(facebookResource?.getBody())
```

Answer (score 0):

**Email** is *not* part of a Facebook [public_profile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-public_profile). The only way to get the users e-mail address is to request extended [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) on the email field. You can do this by **adding a scope** to the oauth provider.

**config.groovy**

```
oauth {
   providers {
      facebook { 
          api = org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
          scope = 'email'
          ...
          ...
      } 
   }
}
```

As an example of how to return `email` and `various public_profile fields` please see below. 
*Take Note of:* `getFacebookResource` params e.g. `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,verified,age_range,email"`

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import org.scribe.model.Token
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauth.OAuthToken

class SpringSecurityOAuthController {

   def oauthService

   def onSuccess = {
      // Validate the 'provider' URL. Any errors here are either misconfiguration
      // or web crawlers (or malicious users).
      if (!params.provider) {
        renderError 400, "The Spring Security OAuth callback URL must include the 'provider' URL parameter."
        return
      }

      def sessionKey = oauthService.findSessionKeyForAccessToken(params.provider)
      if (!session[sessionKey]) {
          renderError 500, "No OAuth token in the session for provider '${params.provider}'!"
          return
      }

      // Create the relevant authentication token and attempt to log in.
      OAuthToken oAuthToken = createAuthToken(params.provider, session[sessionKey])

      Token facebookAccessToken = (Token) session[oauthService.findSessionKeyForAccessToken('facebook')]

      def facebookResource = oauthService.getFacebookResource(facebookAccessToken ,    "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,verified,age_range,email")

      def facebookResponse = JSON.parse(facebookResource?.getBody())

      println facebookResponse

      ...
      ...
    }
}
```

[public_profile (Default)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-public_profile)

A person's public profile refers to the following properties on the user object by default:

- id cover
- name
- first_name
- last_name
- age_range
- link
- gender
- locale
- picture
- timezone
- updated_time
- verified