# Using facebook social plugin how to get email address in grails

Tags: grails, facebook-oauth

I want to get email address using social plugin of grails . I am using  facebook plugin **compile ':spring-security-oauth-facebook:0.1'** and configured properly in **Config.groovy** like below.

```
      oauth {
         debug = true
         providers {
           facebook {
              api = org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
              key = 'here is my-key'
              secret = 'my-secret-key'
              successUri = '/oauth/facebook/success'
              failureUri = '/oauth/facebook/failure'
              callback = "${baseURL}/oauth/facebook/callback"
              scopes = "email"
            }
         }
      }
```

After get successfully response, below method is called.

```
     def onSuccess(String provider) {
      if (!provider) {
        log.warn "The Spring Security OAuth callback URL must include the 'provider' URL 
                  parameter"
        throw new OAuthLoginException("The Spring Security OAuth callback URL must include the 
                                       'provider' URL parameter")
     }
      def sessionKey = oauthService.findSessionKeyForAccessToken(provider)

    if (!session[sessionKey]) {
        log.warn "No OAuth token in the session for provider '${provider}'"
        throw new OAuthLoginException("Authentication error for provider '${provider}'")
      }
    }
    OAuthToken oAuthToken = springSecurityOAuthService.createAuthToken(provider, 
    session[sessionKey])
    println "oAuthToken.principal = "+oAuthToken.principal.toString();
    println "oAuthToken.socialId  = "+oAuthToken.socialId;
    println "oAuthToken.properties= "+oAuthToken.properties
    println "oAuthToken.properties= "+oAuthToken.name
    println "oAuthToken.properties= "+oAuthToken.toString();
```

How to get email address by using this. I successfully get response from facebook but it is same  number for Username,socialId,profileId but i need email Address like **myemailid@gmail.com**

please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get email id from facebook using Grails social plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656681/how-to-get-email-id-from-facebook-using-grails-social-plugin)

Comment: Hi Moore, can u help me